# Computer randomly turning off?

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

My computer randomly turns off with no warning, not even shutting down. I run a minecraft server on it, and it has been corrupted several times. It shut off for the 3rd time in a row today, about 10 minutes apart. It's an old computer, but I've never had the problem until a year ago. I have an MSI 990FXA-GD65 motherboard and an AMD FX 8-core processor, but I am not sure what power supply I have. Is this a sign that the power supply is going bad? I have unplugged and plugged back in all the connections from the power supply, and this still happens.

Comment: Start it with a bootable USB key and let it run. Does it do the same thing?

Comment: I had my server running on a different hard drive with windows 7 before and it still had the same problem. Do you think I should still try a USB key?

Comment: Yes.  Because it is starting to look like a hardware or thermal issue since two operating systems on two different drives have the same problem.

Comment: Have you checked your fans? ESPECIALLY the power supply fan and the CPU fan. Blown 'dust bunnies' from the case?  Checked the core temp of the board?